# stm32f429 USB CDC VCP detection

Tags: stm32, usbserial, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4, stm32f7

[guys i have installed the VCP driver and have loaded the code of USB_CDC in my stm32f429. but the VCP port is not visible in device manager. instead "unknown usb device,(device descriptor request failed)" is shown in device manager, as shown in figure. whom link is given below. kindly help me to solve this issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRzed.png  ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRzed.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you installed the right version of the driver (32 vs 64 bit)?
If you are, then try to increase the heap size in your project (it is located in the startup_stm32f429xx.s file).